# Why does boost::allocate_shared<T> (alloc) ignore alloc.construct() and does std::allocate_shared<T> (alloc) behave alike?

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr, allocator

I want to write a custom allocator which invokes a `createHook()` just after object construction and a symmetrical `destroyHook()` just before object destruction. I am using my allocator this way:

```
class Object {};
class CustomAllocator { /* ... */ };

boost::shared_ptr<Object> object = boost::allocate_shared<Object> (CustomAllocator ());
```

While `allocate_shared<>` correctly calls `allocate()` on my allocator, it does use an in-place `new` statement rather than calling `construct()` on my allocator.

I know how to circumvent this problem in general by writing a custom `my_allocate_shared()` version which invokes the `createHook()` and returns a `shared_ptr<>` instance with a custom deleter (which in turn invokes the `destroyHook()`), but i am loosing the `allocate_shared<>` optimization then.

My coding environment is restricted to C++03, so i don't know how `std::allocate_shared()` in a C++11 context behaves (or should behave).

Comment: I think that's [an open issue](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-active.html#2070).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as `std::allocate_shared` is concerned, the behaviour you're seeing is correct. Quoting C++11 [util.smartptr.shared.create]:

> ```
> template<class T, class... Args> shared_ptr<T> make_shared(Args&&... args);
> template<class T, class A, class... Args>
> shared_ptr<T> allocate_shared(const A& a, Args&&... args);
> ```
>
> 2 *Effects:* Allocates memory suitable for an object of type `T` and constructs an object in that memory
>   via the placement new expression `::new (pv) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...)`. The template
>   `allocate_shared` uses a copy of `a` to allocate memory. If an exception is thrown, the functions have
>   no effect.

Since the standard library shared pointer support is largely based on the Boost implementations, I would say it makes sense that Boost behaves likewise.

As @KerrekSB pointed out in comments, there is apparently a standard library [active issue 2070](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-active.html#2070) about this.

Answer (score 1):

§20.8.2.2.6 [util.smartptr.shared.create]/p1-2:

> ```
> template<class T, class... Args> shared_ptr<T> make_shared(Args&&... args);
> template<class T, class A, class... Args>
> shared_ptr<T> allocate_shared(const A& a, Args&&... args);
> ```
>
> *Requires*: The expression `::new (pv) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...)`, where `pv` has type `void*` and
>   points to storage suitable to hold an object of type `T`, shall be
>   well formed. `A` shall be an allocator (17.6.3.5). The copy
>   constructor and destructor of `A` shall not throw exceptions.
>
> *Effects:* Allocates memory suitable for an object of type `T` and constructs an object in that memory via the placement new expression
>   `::new (pv) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...)`. The template
>   `allocate_shared` uses a copy of `a` to allocate memory. If an
>   exception is thrown, the functions have no effect.

In short, `std::allocate_shared` uses placement new directly rather than the allocator's `construct`.

Comment: Thankx. I was expecting such an answer already. The design of `std::allocator` is (was) a bit misleading then, in my opinion. Is there any `std::` code at all which uses `construct()` on the allocator class? Whenever i use allocators in my code, i call `allocate()` and `construct()` altogether.

Comment: @eel76 Containers that use allocators are required to use `construct()` (and `destroy()`).